# docker run exited right away?

Tags: docker

I have the following Dockerfile so I can login the container to check the image Some_Linux_Img.

```
FROM Some_Linux_Img
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

And I built it

```
docker build -t test:v2 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1/2 : FROM abc.com/shared/miniconda
 ---> ec1a66fb9030
Step 2/2 : ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
 ---> Running in ea14b4ce6c6e
 ---> 21ebe99c7ef1
Removing intermediate container ea14b4ce6c6e
Successfully built 21ebe99c7ef1
```

However, it exited right after `docker run`?

$ docker run --name test test:v2
$ docker ps -a

Status showed "Exited (0) x seconds ago". I wanted to run some bash commands inside the container to check the Linux image `Some_Linux_Img`. (`docker exec -it test /bin/bash`)

Comment: `docker run --rm -it Some_Linux_Img bash` should get you an interactive shell in a temporary container based on that base image.  You need the `-it` option for `bash` to not exit immediately; see the linked question.  You can also override the `CMD` just by passing an alternate command to `docker run`; you don't need a custom image or `docker exec` here.

Answer (score 2):

A container exits when its main process exits and since you have specified the `ENTRYPOINT` as `["/bin/bash"]`, it just executes the command and exits.

If you just want a container to keep running for testing for a few minutes, you could override the entry point command as:

```
docker run --name test test:v2 sleep 300
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as you can see, the exit code of the container is `0`. That means, that the main process (in your case `/bin/bash`) in the container exited without errors.

The problem you have here (in contradiction to what the other answer said) might however be unrelated to the entrypoint or the cmd provided. I think you just wanted to launch a container and enter its bash shell, right?
While this obviously defeats the purpose of containerization, I think it can be very useful for debugging/educational purposes. So here is how to do it (use instead of your `docker run` command):

```
docker run -it --name test test:v2
```

As you can tell, I added the shorthand flags `i` and `t` to your command, what this does is it assigns a tty (`-t`) to your container and starts it in "interactive" mode, meaning you will be able to immediatly interact with the containers shell (`-i`) once it started up.

This of course is only a very basic explaination, please refere to the section I marked in the docker documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground

Comment: Yes, I just want to launch a container and enter its bash shell to check/debug something. I thought the entry point of `/bin/bash` will keep running and the session would wait for commands like type `bash` in the interactive shell. I planned to use `docker exec -it test /bin/bash` to attach the running container.